# How to make a line rendering lay flat on terrain - Unity 2018.3.1

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to lay down a road marking using the line GameObject in Unity 2018.3.1 and there seems to be a problem with the rotation. No matter how I orient the line, it won't lay flat on the terrain. The Unity manual says that the rotation is caused by the alignment being set to "view" and to switch it to "local" instead, however, I can't find that setting in the inspector panel -- I just have "view" and "transform z." Is there a solution to this or another way to lay down a line on the street?

Comment: maybe add a quad with a material thats only white and then scale it so its the line you want? :p

Comment: usually such things are a job for decals. there is a decal shader by unity for the HDRP https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ScriptableRenderPipeline/wiki/Decal-Shader dunno if it helps